# Split an integer

Tags: c#, split, int

I have been searching around the internet for a while but haven't found what I am looking for.

Let me start with some code example:

```
int a = 25;

int b;
int c;
```

What I want to do here is I want to split the `a` variable and give the two values to variable `b` and `c`. The result would be `int b = 2` and `int c = 5`, or vice versa (doesn't matter in the purpose I'm going to use this).

How can you do this?

Comment: I only see one value... you can divide by 10 and put the result in b, while c receives the remainder...

Comment: The flood of downvotes is a little overdone. This is a beginners question but the "no effort" complaint does not really apply here. And with 4 answers one would expect a few more compensation upvotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use integer division and modulo for that:

```
int b = a / 10;
int c = a % 10;
```

If the variable `a` contains a larger number, you would first determine how many digits you want in each variable. If you for example want two digits in `c`, you would use `100` as the second operand in both operations.

Comment: Doh, just wrote the same thing and realised that you'd already answered it :) +1

Comment: simple and sweet answer.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I note that this solution is wrong if the original integer is negative.

Comment: @EricLippert: That depends on what result you expect if the integer is negative.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 6):

One way you could do it is with the following code:

```
int input = 123845;
var digits = input.ToString().Select(x=>int.Parse(x.ToString()));
```

This will first of all convert your input number to a string. It then treats this string as a character array when passing to `Select`. It then converts the char to a string and then parses it as an int, resulting in an `IEnumerable<int>`.

Of note is that this won't work if your input is a negative number (it will complain about the `-`). It wouldn't be too hard to check for the "-" at the beginning if you wanted to though.

The other way is to continually divide by 10 getting all the digits out one by one.

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetDigits(int input)
{
    int currentNumber = input;
    List<int> digits = new List<int>();
    while (currentNumber !=0)
    {
        digits.Add(currentNumber%10);
        currentNumber = currentNumber/10;
    }
    digits.Reverse();
    return digits;
}
```

This will loop through the number adding the last digit to a list as it goes. It then returns the list reversed. This does deal with negative numbers and if the input is negative all output numbers iwll be negative.

An important note is that both of these methods will deal with more than two digits input numbers.

Comment: You don't need to do int.Parse... because due to `input.ToString` it is guaranteed that for positive numbers only number characters are in the string (well, would the question make sense for negative numbers?). So you can write the .Select() as follows: `.Select(c => (int) (c - '0'))`. Well, perhaps not as readable :)

Comment: @Elgonzo: you are totally right that you could write it like that but I don't like the readability as you say. Its probably more efficient but unless you know the trick it is likely to stump you. Good to have as a comment but will leave it out of the answer (since I'm assuming that the OP is not that hot on C# if asking this question).

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 12345;
a = Math.Abs(a);
int length = a.ToString().Length;
int[] array = new int[length];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    array[i] = a % 10;
    a /= 10;
}
```

Comment: What happens if `a` is a negative number?

Comment: It wasn't really a problem. See updates. @EricLippert

Comment: Using .ToString() to determine the number of digits in a base 10 number makes me shudder. Please read up on what a logarithm is.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int myNumber = 123456;
    string myWord = Convert.ToString(myNumber);

    string partOne = myWord.Substring(0, 2);
    string partTwo = myWord.Substring(2, 2);
    string partThree = myWord.Substring(4, 2);

    int num01 = Convert.ToInt32(partOne);
    int num02 = Convert.ToInt32(partTwo);
    int num03 = Convert.ToInt32(partThree);

    Console.WriteLine(num01);
    Console.WriteLine(num02);
    Console.WriteLine(num03);

    Output:
    12
    34
    56
```